# Angularjs external templating: the template cannot be loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates

I thought loading an external template with Angularjs is as simple as this below,

```
<div ng-include='template/index.php'></div>
```

But it does not print anything out on the browser. What have I missed?

The html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Angualr</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-include='template/index.php'></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

the template,

```
<div id='content' ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller='MainController'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:searchText' ng-show='person.live == true'>#{{person.id}} {{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type='text' ng-model='newPerson' />
    <button ng-click='addNew()'>Add</button>

</div>
```

js/app.js,

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[]);
```

js/maincontroller.js,

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){

    $scope.people = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Leon',
            music: [
                'Rock',
                'Metal',
                'Dubstep',
                'Electro'
            ],
            live: true
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Chris',
            music: [
                'Indie',
                'Drumstep',
                'Dubstep',
                'Electro'
            ],
            live: true
        }
    ];
    $scope.newPerson = null;
    $scope.addNew = function() {
        if ($scope.newPerson != null && $scope.newPerson != "") {
            $scope.people.push({
                id: $scope.people.length,
                name: $scope.newPerson,
                live: true,
                music: [
                    'Pop',
                    'RnB',
                    'Hip Hop'
                ]
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Directories,

```
index.html
  js/
   ...
   ...
  template/
    index.php
```

**EDIT 2:**

index.html,

```
<div ng-app='MyTutorialApp'>
        <div ng-include='template/index.php'></div>
    </div>
```

template/index.php,

```
    <div id='content' ng-controller='MainController'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:searchText' ng-show='person.live == true'>#{{person.id}} {{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type='text' ng-model='newPerson' />
    <button ng-click='addNew()'>Add</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Live demo here (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3bIrHFIbO7nYfFL2yYx?p=preview)**

ng-include looks for a $scope property, so you need to pass it a string, like this: `ng-include="'/template/index.php'"`.

```
<div ng-include="'/template/index.php'"></div>
```

What you were passing to it essentially makes it look for this in your controller: `$scope['/template/index.php'] = 'some string';`

You're also bootstrapping angular in the template itself - so how could it be included? `ng-app` needs to be in the main page so that `ng-include` can work!

```
<some-element ng-app="myApp">
  <!-- in here, angular things work (assuming you have created an app called "myApp" -->
  <div ng-include="'/template/index.php'"></div>
</some-element>
```

Just replace `some-element` with something like `html`, `body` or whatever element you want the app to work from.

Comment: @lauthiamkok my updated answer addressed both of your issues.

Comment: thanks for the update. it is still not working. please see my edit 2 above. thanks!

Comment: @lauthiamkok you still aren't following my answer. You're passing `ng-include` a `$scope` property rather than a string. See my live demo. It definitely works, but you have to pass it correctly.

Comment: @lauthiamkok I made you this bizarre example to make my point http://plnkr.co/edit/wP324P2qR5VuSHEvjuy8?p=preview

Comment: thanks m59. it works with your examples and codes. thanks. i still don;t understand why it does not work with my original example but never mind...

Comment: I now facing another problem - `$scope.addNew = function() {...` does not work anymore after using the external templating... any idea why? thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok I was away for a while...could you post a new question about it? This post is cluttered already. Send me the link and I'll check it out.

Comment: hey m59, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779460/angularjs-templating-model-and-function-stop-working-in-external-templates thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-include src='template/index.php'></div>
```

try this

and add ng-app into top of the page

```
<html ng-app='MyTutorialApp'>
```

you must have bootstrap you angular application into your index.html

Comment: is your template folder in the root directory?

Comment: I think so. please take a look on my edit above. thanks.

Comment: just add <html ng-app='MyTutorialApp'>

Answer (score 1):

You bootstrapped your ng-app in the template, but you have to bootstrap it in your main page.
So just move the ng-app directive from the template to the main-page, e.G.

```
<html ng-app="MyTutorialApp">
```