# Angularjs templating: model and function stop working in external templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

After this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775874/angularjs-external-templating-the-template-cannot-be-loaded), I am facing another challenge, the model and function inside the $scope seem have stopped working. Below is the test code, the **Add** button seem does not collect any data I input from `<input type='text' ng-model='newPerson' />` anymore,

html,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller='MainController'>
            <div ng-include='thisIsAScopeProperty'></div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

the external template,

```
<div id='content'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:searchText' ng-show='person.live == true'>#{{person.id}} {{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type='text' ng-model='newPerson' />
    <button ng-click='addNew()'>Add</button>

</div>
```

angularjs,

```
var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp',[]);
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){

    $scope.thisIsAScopeProperty = 'template/index.html';
    $scope.people = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Leon',
            music: [
                'Rock',
                'Metal',
                'Dubstep',
                'Electro'
            ],
            live: true
        }
    ];
    $scope.newPerson = null;
    $scope.addNew = function() {
        alert(1); // works here when you click the Add button
        console.log($scope.newPerson); // but returns nothing when you type any text in the input
        if ($scope.newPerson != null && $scope.newPerson != "") {
            alert(2); // does not work here
            $scope.people.push({
                id: $scope.people.length,
                name: $scope.newPerson,
                live: true,
                music: [
                    'Pop',
                    'RnB',
                    'Hip Hop'
                ]
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas why and how can I fix it?

Comment: yea but why doesn't work on localhost?

Comment: no idea, but try to simplify. include "include" first. there is maybe not wrong with it, but you never know.

Comment: `include "include" first.` sorry what do you mean? how to `include "include" first.`?

Comment: The first step to debug this would be to strip out unnecessary code. Until something starts working OR all of the angular code is gone. Then add a single `$scope` property back and work from there..

Comment: @lauthiamkok Are there any errors in the console log? Here is your exact code (except for the file paths) and it works perfectly. http://plnkr.co/edit/NfxW6r5C1bY5aWUiB06R?p=preview I even tried several versions of Angular to be sure.

Comment: Hey m59, there is no error printed in the console log at all. I am getting frustrated with Angular now. It is too difficult to do do simple things from start! I'm on  AngularJS v1.2.6...

Comment: And I get tons of error for the other test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781006/angularjs-routing-vs-backbonejs-routing it (Angualr) is just ridiculous!

Comment: `ng-include` creates a new scope, which is why `newPerson` isnt' the same property in the included template and the mainController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<input type='text' ng-model='$parent.newPerson' />
```

`ng-include` creates a new scope, and because newPerson is a simple property, it's a different one on the child and parent scopes (i.e. changing one doesn't change the other). So when the included template sets `newPerson` it's still null on the mainController's scope.

For a better understanding of how scopes work, read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: @lauthiamkok ohhh, man, I could have solved this so quickly. It isn't clear in your question that this was your problem. You said `$scope` wasn't working, so it sounded like no data-binding was working at all. This was just a problem of child scope inheritance.

Comment: yea sorry was new to angular and find it quite intimidating.