# Angularjs routing Vs Backbonejs routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, backbone.js

I am getting frustrated with Angualrjs as it keeps throwing errors or just fails to work at all on my localhost despite I have followed the tutorial exactly. For instance this [tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/ED2k8dybMw/angularjs-ng-view) which I want to test out the routing.

And this is what I get,

> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.6%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0As%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%0AYb%2Fm.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%0Ac%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%0AYb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%0AXb%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%0AXb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%0ARc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A200%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.10.1.min.js%3A4%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fp.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.10.1.min.js%3A4%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.10.1.min.js%3A4%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2F2013%2Fjs%2Fangular%2F3%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.10.1.min.js%3A4%0A
>
> ...c-1)+"="+encodeURIComponent("function"==typeof
>   arguments[c]?arguments[c].toStrin...

This is how I could do it in Backbonejs easily!

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '':                 'renderListContactsPage',
            'list_contacts':    'renderListContactsPage', 
            'add_new_contact':  'renderAddNewContactPage', 
            'search_contacts':  'renderSearchContactsPage', 
            'edit_contact/:id':     'renderEditContactPage',
            '!article/edit/:url/':    'renderDynamicPage',
             ':parent/:url/':    'renderDynamicPage2',
            '!:module/:branch/:method/set:setnumber/page:pagenumber/':   'renderDynamicPage3',
            '!:module/:branch/:method?set=:setnumber&page=:pagenumber': 'renderDynamicPage3'
        },

        renderAddNewContactPage: function () {
            var projectAddView = new ProjectAddView();
            projectAddView.addContactPage();

        }, 

        renderListContactsPage: function () {
            var projectListView = new ProjectListView();
            projectListView.listContactsPage();
        }, 

        renderSearchContactsPage: function () {
            var projectSearchView = new ProjectSearchView();
            projectSearchView.searchContactPage();
        }

...
```

What have I missed in Angular? I am using the latest version of it - **v1.2.6** and they have such a poor documentation!

**EDIT:**

html,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-app="app">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

angular,

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "app.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl"
    }
  );
});

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.model = {
    message: "This is my app!!!"
  }
});
```

Comment: You haven't included the [ngRoute module](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular-route.js) which is distributed as a separate module in newer versions of angular. Also, seems you're quite biased to Backbone so maybe you should stay with it to keep your nerves.

Comment: I get the min file from http://angularjs.org/ and it does not mention about the the routing module or providing any link to document about any other modules. Such a poor website...

Comment: well, I get the same frustrating error even though I have included the routing module. please take a look at my edit above. thanks.

Comment: No, you haven't included the ngRoute module, because you haven't specified it as a dependency as in: `angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);`. I advise reading the docs and not relying on unofficial tutorials (although Lindquist screencasts are awesome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `ngRoute` to be injected as a dependency in your module declaration.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

should be

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "app.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl"
    }
  );
}]);
```